# pm2 launching from a JSON not working

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm trying to launch my `app` from an `app.json` file:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "app",
    "cwd": "/Users/xxx/Sites/Projects/api/",
    "script": "bin/www",
    "instances": 1,
    "exec_mode": "fork",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "dev",
      "PORT": "3000"
    },
    "env_production" : {
      "NODE_ENV": "production",
      "PORT": "3000"
    },
    "log_file": "access.log",
    "error_file": "error.log",
    "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "watch": "true",
    "ignore_watch": [""]
  }]
}
```

The problem comes when I use the JSON to launch my app.

```
pm2 start applist.json

[PM2][WARN] Applications app not running, starting...
```

If I launch the app without a JSON, it works like a charm.

```
pm2 start bin/www --watch
```

Any help with this?

Comment: This is just a warning. Everything should work.

Comment: Altough this is a warning, when I save the project, It doesn't refresh the instance. It seems that the watcher is not working. Seems there's a bug